# Where are all the places needed to change a host name for a web service call

Tags: c#, web-services

I am using VS 2012 under windows 7x64.  I have a winforms application that makes a webservice call to a Java (JBOSS) server.  On the client-side I created the connection using Add Service Reference.  Everything was generated properly and the communcation between client and my development server works.  Now, I would like to point my client at a different server for QA purposes.  I researched this and found I should change the app.config, specifically the endpoint address:

```
 <endpoint address="http://devserver01.mydomain.org:80/af-afejb3/TransmitWS_003" ...>
```

I did this and it seems to work but my question is around other places I may need to change.  I did a text search of my entire solution for the old dev server name (devserver01.mydomain.org) and found it still existed in several places including:
configuration.svcinfo,
configuration91.svcinfo,
configuration91.svcinfo,
TransmitWS_003.wsdl,
Reference.svcmap

My thinking is that these files must not matter but I am uncomfortable seeing the old server names within certain files still in my codebase.  Are the above files throw-away files that I should not commit to version control?  I certainly like the idea of making a simple change to the app.config and this does feel right but I want to be sure.  Is the app.config the only place?

thanks

Comment: Another way to ask the above question is: should I manually change the *.svcinfo files so that the old server references are deleted and updated to point to the current server?  By the way, this question is somewhat rhetorical as I really don't think Microsoft wants these files changed manually.  Really, I need a good resource to help me understand HOW these files (configuration.svcinfo, configuration91.svcinfo, configuration91.svcinfo, TransmitWS_003.wsdl, Reference.svcmap) are used in the process.

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444753/scvmap-disco-xsd-wsdl-svcinfo-and-datasource-files.  It's not exact but interesting stuff here.

Comment: Another good reference here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439364/what-are-the-wcf-service-reference-datasource-files

Comment: I'm wrapping this one up.  Looks like having some of these generated files that become out-of-sync with app.config is no big deal.  They can probably be removed, but I plan on keeping them around because they could have some use within the VS2012 environment.