# Do I need WSDL, DISCO, SVCINFO files to USE a webservice?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I have an **ASP.Net website** that **use** some webservices.
For each webservice used by my project I have a folder full of scvmap / disco / wsdl / svcinfo files.

Do these wsdl/disco/svcinfo files need to exist on the web server so that my website can USE the referenced webservice?
Do I need to upload them on my webserver?

Comment: possible duplicate of [scvmap, disco, xsd, wsdl, svcinfo and datasource files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444753/scvmap-disco-xsd-wsdl-svcinfo-and-datasource-files)

Comment: @CodeCaster NOT a duplicate, the linked question is about which files need to be put in source control versioning system. It doesn't answer the question "do I need these files to exist on the web server so that my website can USE the referenced webservice?"

Comment: If you try to find the commonalities instead of the differences, you'll find the sentence in the accepted answer _"You can actually delete them since they were just use when the reference file is being generated."_ particularly relevant. The fact that they don't get copied when you publish your site should also give you a hint.

Comment: @CodeCaster sure, but the sentence "You can actually delete them since they were just use when the reference file is being generated." relate to "xsd" files, and I don't have a single xsd files in my folder

Comment: Then read on to the second answer: _"Reference.cs contains the generated contracts and proxy against which your code is compiled [...] All of the other files are TEMPORARY files"_. Granted, that question should be revised to be a bit broader and the answers could be edited to be a little more factual, but in my opinion the answer to your question is in there.

Comment: @CodeCaster If I had the knowledge to deduce the answer to my question, from the question you linked, I would have done that. If asked a question, is because I haven't found a satisfying answer. It's very presumptuous that you think you know what other people should be able to deduce from other answers to other questions. As of today I've been unable to find a clear direct answer to my question. If you have the knowledge to write a better answer to another question, that also respond to my question, please do it. Or give my question a direct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the **wsdl/disco/svcinfo** files **are not needed** on the web server for a website to access a wabservice.

I tried to remove the folder containing those files from the webserver, and the website happily continued to being able to use the webservice.

Anyway **I'm not an expert about webservices**. This is the first time I need to deploy something that use a webservice, so, please, take this answer "as-is" :-)